# searching in n 2-dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops

Help with how to implement searching on n 2-dimenssional arrays. To be more specific:
If I have 6 tables and I am putting these into a 2-dimensional array.I will provide a value say 10 like how val=0 here. I need to search from these tables all the combination values that make up 10. The value will be computed taking values from all these tables.

```
public static int Main() {
  int[] a = {2,1,4,7};
  int[] b = {3,-3,-8,0};
  int[] c = {-1,-4,-7,6};
  int sum;
  int i; int j;  int k;
  int val = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(j = 0;j<4;j++) {
      for(k = 0;k<4;k++) {
        sum = a[i]* b[j]* c[k];

        if(sum == val)
          System.out.printf("%d  %d  %d\n",a[i],b[j],c[k]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any 2 dimensional array in code or am I missing something?

Comment: @ Harray true there is no 2 dimensional array in this code but that's the need here, to implement on 2dimensional array. I am struggling with this oly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider a table as list of values. Then, if you have N tables, your problem is to find lists of N integers (each one taken from one of the N tables) whose product is equal to a value p. You can solve the problem recursively:

- given a non-empty list of tables `{t1, t2, t3, ...}`
- given a product value `p` that you look for
- for every value `v` in `t1` you must look for solutions of the sub-problem with a product value `p / v` and and tables `{t2, t3, ...}` (this assumes that `p % v == 0`, because we're dealing with integers
- etc.

Some java code below:

```
public class SO6026472 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // define individual tables
        Integer[] t1 = new Integer[] {2,-2,4,7};
        Integer[] t2 = new Integer[] {3,-3,-8,0};
        Integer[] t3 = new Integer[] {-1,-4,-7,6};
        Integer[] t4 = new Integer[] {1,5};
        // build list of tables
        List<List<Integer>> tables = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        tables.add(Arrays.asList(t1));
        tables.add(Arrays.asList(t2));
        tables.add(Arrays.asList(t3));
        tables.add(Arrays.asList(t4));
        // find solutions
        SO6026472 c = new SO6026472();
        List<List<Integer>> solutions = c.find(36, tables);
        for (List<Integer> solution : solutions) {
            System.out.println(
                    Arrays.toString(solution.toArray(new Integer[0])));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Computes the ways of computing p as a product of elements taken from 
     * every table in tables.
     * 
     * @param p the target product value
     * @param tables the list of tables
     * @return the list of combinations of elements (one from each table) whose
     * product is equal to p
     */
    public List<List<Integer>> find(int p, List<List<Integer>> tables) {
        List<List<Integer>> solutions = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        // if we have no tables, then we are done
        if (tables.size() == 0)
            return solutions;
        // if we have just one table, then we just have to check if it contains p
        if (tables.size() == 1) {
            if (tables.get(0).contains(p)) {
                List<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                solution.add(p);
                solutions.add(solution);
                return solutions;
            } else
                return solutions;
        }
        // if we have several tables, then we take the first table T, and for
        // every value v in T we search for (p / v) in the rest of the tables;
        // we do this only if p % v is equal to 0, because we're dealing with
        // ints
        List<Integer> table = tables.remove(0);
        for (Integer value : table) {
            if (value != 0 && p % value == 0) {
                List<List<Integer>> subSolutions = find(p / value, tables);
                if (! subSolutions.isEmpty()) {
                    for (List<Integer> subSolution : subSolutions) {
                        subSolution.add(0, value);
                    }
                    solutions.addAll(subSolutions);
                }
            }
        }
        tables.add(0, table);
        return solutions;
    }

}
```

The code prints solutions for a slightly modified version of your example:

```
[2, 3, 6, 1]
[-2, -3, 6, 1]
```

The solutions work for any number of tables. There are ways to improve the algorithm, for example by using memoization and dynamic programming. But I think that the recursive solution is more clear.

Comment: Hi Macros , thanks for the help and the sol but I was looking for Multiplication operation to take place .Here the combination that we are geting is addition. I Hope you got my point.

Comment: @user756742: oh, sorry! I got confused. However, the idea is the same even for product. I've changed my code, so that is now consistent with your question: the recursive procedure gives you all the combination of elements from your table whose product is equal to a certain value. Have a look and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: @ Macros - I just ahead on ur code to read from an excel and to print de coloum and rows name . I have encontered one problem pls provide me your valuable solution.
Cell[][] newcell=new Cell[200][200];
int newsheet = workbook1.getNumberOfSheets();
for (int q=1;q<newsheet;q++)
{
for(int p=0;p<sheet(q).getColumns();p++)
{
for(int p1=0;p1<sheet(q).getRows();p1++)
(
newcell[p][p1] = sheet(q).getCell(p, p1);
if(newcell[p][p1].equals(saved[j]))
{
System.out.print( newcell[p][0]);
}
}
Can I use the property of sheet() as sheet(q) because its throughing NullPointer Exception?

Comment: @user756742: I'm afraind I can't help you here: it seems that you're accessing a spreadsheet with some Java API. Possibly `workbook1` is already `null`: check this. Also, is `sheet()` a method? I believe you have another problem here, related to how to read a spreadsheet from Java: this is unrelated to your question above; you may consider asking a new specific question on your code that reads the spreadsheet.

Comment: @MAcros U R rite m reading frm a spreadsheet. Thanks for the input:) Will post as a new Q ...

Answer (score 2):

Following will be the code you require:

(The solution includes recursion making your problem go easier)

```
private ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();

public void CalculateSum(int tableNumber)
{
    if(!Tables.isLast(tableNumber))
    {
        int[][] a = Tables.Get(tableNumber);
        for(int y = 0; y < a.length; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < a[y].length; x++)
            {
                numbers.add(a[y][x]);
                CalculateSum(tableNumber + 1);
                numbers.remove(tableNumber - 1);
            }
        }
    }else
    {
        int[][] a = Tables.Get(tableNumber);
        for(int y = 0; y < a.length; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < a[y].length; x++)
            {
                if((sum(numbers) + a[y][x]) == checkValue)
                {
                    PrintNumbers(numbers);
                    System.out.print(a[y][x]);
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

You need to implement a class ('Tables' as my solution) write methods:

boolean isLast(int tableNo): to check whether the given table is the last table your tables list

int[][] Get(int tableNo): to get the table with the specified index

Also the method sum should sum the values in the numbers ArrayList.
PrintNumbers method should print the numbers in the numbers ArrayList in a row.
checkValue is the value you want to check.

Hope this helps....

Please write if you want any clarification on this algorithm.

Comment: but m looking for where we can implement this on n arrys this satisfy for 2 or 3 arrays if I have 6 then this will not workout.

Comment: Do you want the number of tables to be variable??? Or do you know the number of tables exactly when you are writing the code?

Comment: number of table will read into arrays. N number of tables will not be know. That's the funda here ...

Comment: I ll try to provide you the answer